Load data into excel file in s3
Hi guys Im currently integrating my local ETL Pipeline into AWS cloud platform. Im using Amazon MWAA service for this. I currently have a problem with loading my retrieved data into an excel file which is inside my s3 bucket. With my local pipeline I use openpyxl to manipulate the excel file, below are the code for my local etl pipeline (this function is to load the data into the excel file in my local folder.
def export_andbeyond_to_excel(ti):
    df = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='transform_andbeyond')
    excel_file = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='latest_file')
    master_wb =openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
    master_sheets =  master_wb.active #open the sheets

    table = master_sheets['Q71':'Q89']  # Select all cells in column I from row 27 to the row 46
    for i, row in enumerate(table, start=70):
        site = row[0].value
        if site in df['Sites'].values:
            index = df.index[df['Sites'] == site].tolist()[0]
            master_sheets[f'R{i+1}'] = df.at[index, 'Impressions']
            master_sheets[f'S{i+1}'] = df.at[index, 'Revenue']
        else:
            master_sheets[f'R{i+1}'] = 0
            master_sheets[f'S{i+1}'] = 0

    # Save the workbook
    master_wb.save(excel_file)


I want to do the same thing on AWS, where the excel file is in the s3 folder. The 'latest_file' is from another function where it will locate the latest file created and this 'export_andbeyond_to_excel' will then load data into the 'latest_file'.
Anybody can suggest me how can I do the same thing on local to cloud platform?
If can, I dont want it to download from s3 and upload to s3 again

Use boto3 to download the file from S3, manipulate it, upload it back to S3…‽

Im using boto3, can I not download and upload or is that the only way to manipulate the excel file? @deceze

That's pretty much the way. Why don't you want to do that?

I thought I need to download it to local and upload it back to cloud, but I download it in memory with io modules, thanks tho.

def export_andbeyond_to_excel(ti):
df = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='transform_andbeyond')
excel_file_key = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='latest_file')
bucket_name = 'data-invertory-partner-s3'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket_name, Key = excel_file_key)
excel_data = response['Body'].read()
excel_file = BytesIO(excel_data)


master_wb =openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file) #open excel
master_sheets =  master_wb.active #open the sheets

table = master_sheets['Q71':'Q89']  # Select all cells in column I from row 27 to the row 46
for i, row in enumerate(table, start=70):
    site = row[0].value
    if site in df['Sites'].values:
        index = df.index[df['Sites'] == site].tolist()[0]
        master_sheets[f'R{i+1}'] = df.at[index, 'Impressions']
        master_sheets[f'S{i+1}'] = df.at[index, 'Revenue']
    else:
        master_sheets[f'R{i+1}'] = 0
        master_sheets[f'S{i+1}'] = 0

# Save the workbook to a BytesIO object
output = BytesIO()
master_wb.save(output)
output.seek(0)  # Important: move back to the start of the BytesIO object before uploading

# Upload the updated file back to S3
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=excel_file_key, Body=output.getvalue())

# Cleanup
output.close()

The updated code for s3. Download from s3 and upload back to s3.
